# How to partly update Cesium mesh terrain dataset?

Tags: gdal, cesium, quantized-mesh

I started working with mesh terrain to feed cesium and I have a doubt. I have generated the entire planet using the SRTM1 DEM dataset. Now, I would like to generate a more detailed view for zoom 13/14 utilizing a dataset from some countries with more precision, 5 meters resolution. This new dataset would be only for zoom 13 and 14. The entire world zooms are from 0 - 14 zoom. I can easily merge both datasets using GDAL virtual files.

My doubt is, to add this new dataset to the entire globe (in mesh format), do I need to generate again the zooms 13 and 14?

Is there any trick to generating only the zoom for the new dataset and then merging with the entire planet?